# Using resulting lcmm model to make predictions for new individuals

Tags: r, classification, prediction

I've applied lcmm (in R) to a large dataset of individuals for which I have a response measure at multiple time points and several covariates (which were included in the model).

1. How can I use the resulting model to predict/assign a new individual to one of the resulting classes? i.e given an lcmm model and a new individual, can I predict which class he is likely to belong to? I cannot find the R function for this.
2. Can this be done if for the new individual only the covariates are known (when no response measure data is available)?

Thanks!